Why does a SQL CLR project require that assemblies be copied to the publish folder?
I have to publish a SQL CLR project that passes unit tests. It consists of a very lean SQL CLR assembly whose actual SQL functions wrap methods of classes from another class library that contains most of the functionality. This latter assembly has several Nuget packages installed and brings along a few dozens of referenced DLLs.
When I proceed to create assemblies in SQL, it begins to rain errors that tell me that one after another assembly is not found. They are assemblies in the stock deployment of .NET that are already present in the GAC. If copied from either GAC or .NET installation folder to the publish folder, each of them satisfies the error and throws the next similar error about another such missing assembly.
Some of them are not even used, and the class library works without them present in the output directory.
I thought that the whole purpose of .NET and GAC was to not to have to copy DLLs about, but this deluge of DLL errors attests to the opposite. How are such missing references supposed to be satisfied from the perspective of SQL Server and .NET design?
